# Cannot Cast Array as float32

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to cast an array as `float32`, but I keep getting:

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Here is the code that triggers the above error:

```
W = np.random.randn(M1, K) / np.sqrt(M1 + K)
self.W = tf.Variable(W)
self.W = tf.cast(self.W, tf.float32)
```

When I attempt to

```
self.W = tf.cast(self.W, tf.int64)
```

I dont get an error.

When I try casting to `float32` with Numpy methods, I run into the same error.

Comment: Does the `TF` documentation say you can cast a `tf.Variable`?  Maybe it isn't a regular number or numpy array.  Can you explain what it is, and how it differs?

Comment: The documentation for `tf.cast` says the first argument is a tensor.  It says nothing about a Variable.  Are you clear about the difference between those 2 classes?

Comment: I just tried running this with `M1=2` and `K=3` and it works fine. Could you try updating your tensorflow installation maybe?